# Given three sets $A, B, C$ such that $A \subset \wp (B) \subset C$, with $|A| = 2$, is it possible that $|C| = 4$ $?$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given this:

We have three sets $A, B, C$ such that $A \subset \wp (B) \subset C$, with $|A| = 2$

I must say whether it's true or false that "$|C|$ can be $5$, but not $4$". My response would be that it's false, since:

$A$ is a proper subset of $\wp(B)$, therefore $\wp(B)$ has at least one more element than $A$, so $|\wp(B)|\geq3$

Also, $\wp(B)$ is a proper subset of $C$, so by the same logic, $|C| \geq 4$

So in conclusion, $|C|$ can indeed be $4$.

Is this right? It may seem simple since it's just an intro to proofs textbook problem, but I'm not sure if I'm missing something, since I didn't use the fact that I'm given the $\wp(B)$ instead of just $B$.

Thanks.

Comment: $|\wp(X)| = 2^{|X|}$.

Comment: By the way, your statement "$A$ is a proper subset of $\wp(B)$" is wrong. $A$ is an *element* of $\wp(B)$, but $A$ is **NOT** a *subset* of $\wp(B)$.

Comment: @zipirovich I'm not sure I follow. Doesn't "$A \subset \wp(B)$ mean that $A$ is a proper subset of $\wp(B)$? Otherwise the exercise would state "$A \in \wp(B)$" , if it was an element.

Comment: What does $\wp (B)$ mean?

Comment: My bad: I read $\wp(A)$ instead of $\wp(B)$. I'm taking my comment back. I was completely wrong. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true, because the power set of a set with $n$ elements will itself have $2^n$ elements. This means that the smallest number of elements the power set of $B$ can have is 4 (ie the smallest power of $2$ which is strictly greater than 2).

If the power set of $B$ has at least 4 elements, then $C$ must have at least one more than this, so must at least have 5.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathcal P(B)$ is an even number because $|\mathcal P (B)|=2^{|B|}$. Hence, since $|A|=2$ and $A\subsetneq \mathcal P(B) \subsetneq C$ only $|C|\geq 5$ is possible.